# problema en AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

pensaba que estos mensajes estaban relacionados con otro problema que tenia, pero se han corregido y me siguen apareciendo.

Me podies decir como puedo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir a la opcion **un-inject Lenguaje/Reference** presionando `Ctrl + Shift + A` y escribe **un-inject Lenguage/Reference** y luego presiona Enter. Recompila y listo.

En caso de que no te aparezca, ve a `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Intentions ->` y busca por Un-Inject Lenguage/Reference y desmarcalo o descarlo segun si esta o no.

Comment: Hola @Einer, me muestra este mensaje http://funkyimg.com/i/2At5W.png y no da opción a presiones Enter

Comment: Estraño. A mi me aparece desde que escribo **un-**. Dale una mirada a la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: quieres decir al post que tengo abierto sobre "targetSdkVersion no compatible", ya he comentado en ese post que android studio esta actualizado. si es verdad que hay otra cosa que la primera vez me salto un aviso, y ley como desactivarlo, es esto http://funkyimg.com/i/2Atxw.png no se si tengo que instalar algo.

Comment: Hola Einer, no he visto la modificación que haces en el post que creaste, he seguido los pasos y tampoco aparece, mira esta captura http://funkyimg.com/i/2AtEu.png no se si es porque tengo que instalar algo, no se porque no aparece para poder solucionar esos errores que aparecen.

Comment: Que version de android studio utilizas?

Comment: cuando voy a actualizar dice que tengo la ultima, mira la información que muestra http://funkyimg.com/i/2AtPf.png .... no te respondo antes porque no recibo notificaciones de nueva respuestas, es un fastidio.

Comment: Hola @Einer no se si tienes que comentar algo sobre la versión que te digo que tengo instalada, pero he probado con otro proyecto y esta vez si que he podido mostrar las opciones que dices, y he probado a desactivarlo y volviendo a activar y pasa lo mismo, en este caso el <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> tiene un nombre diferente y sigue mostrando estos errores http://funkyimg.com/i/2AxoT.png